# Configuring authentication for webpack proxy

Tags: authentication, proxy, webpack

I have a .Net Web API service running with windows authentication enabled. I've a separate UI application for which webpack is setup. I'm trying to setup webpack proxy to access my service. Here is my current configuration

```
 "proxy": {
      "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:50643",
    }
  }
```

I'm getting a 401 (Unauthorized) error now. How do I setup webpack proxy to enable authentication.

Answer (score 3):

You can provide `auth` prop:

`"proxy": {
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:50643",
    "auth": "username:password"
  }
}`

Comment: How do I use windows/ntlm auth?

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to do this with windows authentication?

Comment: Great, it works for basic auth. One issue which is bothering me: neither for version v3 https://webpack-v3.jsx.app/configuration/dev-server/ nor for version v4 https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/ there is such property in docs.

Comment: @CodeMonkey It's documented here https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware